# How to provide credentials for Spring app via OkHttp and Retrofit

Tags: java, spring-boot, retrofit2, basic-authentication, okhttp

I develop spring non-web service which has webflux basic authentication.
Its working and i am able to successfully use cURL to reach certain endpoints like:

```
curl -I --user user:password http://localhost:5051/service/v1/health
or
curl -I http://user:password@localhost:5051/service/v1/health
```

But now im trying to send post via other services which use OkHttp and Retrofit to communicate with my spring service.

This process is more complicated, in main apllication, the OkHttpCllient is created and then separate, Retrofit service client provider is called.

**The main application:**

```
    httpUrl = url
                .newBuilder()
                .username(Username) // first approach
                .password(Password)
                {..}
                .build();
```

```
     ClientProvider
                .getInstance(httpUrl, Username, Password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new ProfiledSingleObserver<Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public void profiledOnError(@NotNull Throwable e) {
                        LOG.error("Transport layer error", e);
                        resultFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
                    }

            @Override
                    public void profiledOnSuccess(@NotNull Event event) {
                        resultFuture.complete(Collections.singleton(event));
                    }
                });
```

```
public class ClientProvider {
    private static HttpUrl httpUrl = null;
    private static Service instance = null;

    private ClientProvider() {
    }

    public static Service getInstance(final HttpUrl url, String username, String password) {
      
                instance = Client.createService(url, HttpClient.getInstance(username, password));
         
        return instance;
    }
}
```

```
  public static OkHttpClient getInstance(String username, String password) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                instance = new OkHttpClient.Builder()

//                        .authenticator(new Authenticator() { // second approach
//                            @Override
//                            public Request authenticate(@Nullable Route route, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
//                                return response
//                                        .request().newBuilder()
//                                        .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password))
//                                        .build();
//                            }
//                        })
//                        .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor(username,password)) // third approach
                        .addInterceptor(createHttpBodyLoggingInterceptor())
                        .addInterceptor(createHttpBasicLoggingInterceptor())
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .dispatcher(createDispatcher())
                        .connectionPool(createConnectionPool())
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final String credentials;

    public BasicAuthInterceptor(String user, String password) {
        this.credentials = Credentials.basic(user, password);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request authenticatedRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, credentials).build();
        return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
    }
}
```

**And the Retrofit service client provider:**

```
 public static Service createService(final HttpUrl baseUrl, final OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return createRetrofit(baseUrl, okHttpClient).create(Service.class);
    }

    protected static Retrofit createRetrofit(HttpUrl baseUrl, OkHttpClient client) {

        return new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

I was taking 3 different approach to solve this problem, as u can see in the comments next to them.
First was just passing username and password via url to look something like:

```
 http://user:password@localhost:5051/service/v1/health
```

but even if curl with this notation is working, authentication did not pass.

Second approach was with  creating Authenticator in OkHttpClient.Builder().
Still the same results.

And third one was with creating Interceptor also in the OkHttpClient.
In this approach i was able to pass unit tests with stubbed server,
which was impossible in other solutions ( Status 404, Not found):

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        serviceStubServer = new StubServer();
        whenHttp(serviceStubServer)
                .match(Condition.basicAuth("user", "pass"), Condition.post("/service/v1/health"))
                .then(
                        Action.status(HttpStatus.OK_200),
                );
        serviceStubServer.run();
    }
```

But still i was unable to send records to my Spring service via my main appplication( Status 401, Unauthorized).

My question is, whats the correct way to pass credentials thru OkHttp and Retrofit to be able to reach endpoints in Spring non-web, webflux basic authentication secure application?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was with singleton approach to create OkHttpClient. This system was operating with two different Spring services and remembered one of the credentials, so he was unable to correctly reach second service.
To solve this problem i create second OkHttpClient class and use the "Interceptor" method to provide authorization data.